# Evaluating a simple integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate a simple integral with basic rules we learned : 
$$\int\frac{2t+3}{9t^2-12t+8}dt$$
However I try, I fail. I tried substitution, splitting into two integrals and also square completion so I have this :
$$\int\frac{2t+3}{9(t-\frac{2}{3})^2+4}dt$$
But it still leads me nowhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You can split the given integral into
$$
\int\frac{2t+3}{9t^2-12t+8}dt=a\int\frac{(9t^2-12t+8)'}{9t^2-12t+8}dt+b\int\frac{1}{9(t-\frac{2}{3})^2+4}dt.
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: You find that $a=\dfrac19$, $b=\dfrac{13}3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can figure a, but not b. I can't see how this fraction is helping..

Comment: You want to have $18at-12a+b=2t+3$ for all $t$, this gives $18a=2$ and $-12a+b=3$, thus $b=3+12a=3+12/9=13/3$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @shlogek You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolab may help you

" https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B2t%2B3%7D%7B9t%5E%7B2%7D-12t%2B8%7Ddt "

text text text text text text text text

Comment: It might be better to explain each step taken toward evaluating the integral rather than post a link to an algorithm.

Comment: I mean im not a professor or anything, the guy was asking for help, and I found the answer on Symbolab, why not share?

Comment: Thank you for the link! I'll keep it in my favs

Comment: @RicardoSilvestre To answer your question "why not share", please see the help page for mathstackexchange.com: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer, the section about sharing links.